# iPhone: Screen not redrawing when I do something heavy _afterwards_

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to post a message and a picture to twitter (using a picture hoster). If the user enters a message alone and then taps send my overlay appears and shows "Sending message to twitter".
If the user adds a picture it doesn't show that overlay. Maybe because he has to convert it to jpg and thats heavy load?
My code looks like this:

```
[overlayMessage changeTextTo:NSLocalizedString(@"keySendTwitter", nil)];
overlayMessage.hidden = NO; 
overlayMessage.locked = YES;

// I've added these out of desperation :P
[overlayMessage setNeedsDisplay];
[self.view setNeedsDisplay];

[self sendMessage];
```

It seems like the two messages (changeTextTo: and sendMessage:) are running in parallel and that sendMessage is a little bit faster with doing the heavy loading. But that would require threading and my app is not multithreaded.

Or maybe setNeedsDisplay: is the wrong message to update the screen before the heavy loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% clear what you're doing, but it sounds like your `[self sendMessage]` method is blocking the UI from updating. Which makes sense if you're doing a large synchronous network operation or image conversion. You don't have to mess around too much with threading to get the UI to be responsive during heavy operations. simply call `sendMessage` on a different thread with:

```
[self performSelector@selector(sendMessage) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.001f];
```

or

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(sendMessage) withObject:nil];
```

Your method will end, your UI will update (no need for `setNeedsDisplay`, probably) and your `sendMessage` selector will fire. You are in charge of making sure `sendMessage` causes your loading screen to be dismissed, but you'll think of something for that :)

The key idea here is that interface updates happen in batches. A bit of your code runs, and then the interface updates... another bit of your code runs, and the interface updates.

What's happening here is that your code is too bulky, and the ui can't update until it's done. Calling `setNeedsDisplay` only marks a view as "dirty" and in need of redrawing, it doesn't actually re-draw the view.

I suggest either break your operation into asynchronous chunks, use `NSOperationQueue`, or use one of the `performSelector` variants.

Comment: I know about performSelector. But the code at sendMessage is from ShareKit. Its not made wit threading in mind :P

Comment: so does it crash when you use performSelector?

Comment: I'm guessing your real problem is the image resize operation. ShareKit will be doing async network operations. Is there any way to do this ahead of time, or in the background with NSOperationQueue? In my photo apps I have an NSOperationQueue processing all new photos into a thumbnail and a screen image (along with the high rez)

Comment: Also consider the tradeoff of downsizing images before sharing. You don't need to send a 1600x1200 photo to twitpic. Obviously higher quality is better, but there is a balance between quality and responsiveness/bandwidth.

Comment: @Kenny Winker: Just for the record: maybe you could clarify in your answer a little bit, that `setNeedsDisplay` does *not* cause the screen to be repainted, but simply marks the view as being "dirty". The title of the original post seems to imply, that the OP thinks, that the painting would be done by the call to `setNeedsDisplay`, which is not the case.

Comment: @Dirk, definitely! I was hinting at that, but I should probably have been clearer.